# Derivation of Riemann Explicit formula from Von Mangoldt formula

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

To drive Riemann explicit formula for counting of primes $$J(x)=li(x)-\sum_{ρ}li(x^ρ )-log⁡(2)+\int_x^∞\frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)  log⁡(t) }\qquad (1)$$

One can start from Von Mangoldt formula  $$ψ(x)=x -\sum_{ρ}\frac{x^ρ}{ρ}-\frac{1}{2}log(1-\frac{1}{x^2})-log⁡(2π) \qquad (2)  $$
knowing that $dψ=log(x) dJ$ we can find J'(x) as

$$J'(x) =\frac{dJ(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{log(⁡x)}\frac{dψ}{dx}$$
$$J'(x)=\frac{1}{log(x)}-\frac{1}{log(x)}\sum_{ρ}x^{ρ-1}-\frac{1}{x(x^2-1)  log⁡(x) }$$
And now integrating from 0 to x we get
$$J(x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{log(t)}-\sum_{ρ}\int_0^x\frac{t^{ρ-1}}{log(t)}dt-\int_0^x\frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)  log⁡(t) }$$
which yields
$$J(x)=li(x)-\sum_{ρ}li(x^ρ )-\int_0^x\frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)  log⁡(t) }\qquad (3)$$
And now comparing eq (3) to eq (1)  we see that the first two terms match fine but not the third one! What did go wrong in the derivation?

Comment: The function $\frac{1}{{t(t^2  - 1)\log t}}$ has a non-integrable singularity at $t=1$. The integral from $0$ to $x>1$ does not exist, even if you consider the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: But Gary, how do you proceed then from J'(x) to obtain J(x)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the definitions, $J(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ satisfies the following identies:
$$
J(x)=\sum_{p^k\le x}\frac1k=\sum_{p^k\le x}{\log p\over\log p^k}
=\sum_{1.5<n\le x}{\Lambda(n)\over\log n} \\
\psi(x)=\sum_{p^k\le x}\log p=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)
$$

where $\Lambda(n)=[n=p^k]\log p$ is von Mangolt function. Now, using Abel's summation formula, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(x)
&=\left.\psi(t)\over\log t\right|_{1.5}^x-\int_{1.5}^x\psi(t)\mathrm d\left(1\over\log t\right) \\
&={\psi(x)\over\log x}-{\psi(1.5)\over\log(1.5)}+\int_{1.5}^x{\psi(t)\over t\log^2t}
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\psi(x)\equiv0$ for all $x<2$, we can simplify this into
$$
J(x)={\psi(x)\over\log x}+\int_2^x{\psi(x)\over t\log^2t}\mathrm dt
$$
Now, plugging the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ sh